# MaxPermSize work around for Java 8.0

Tags: java, batch-file, java-8

I have an old game I'm trying to run from a batch file that's a big file size. Before it was using MaxPermSize, but java not longer does that so it just stops after using too much default memory. This is the batch code:

```
start java Lobby.StartLobby 
start java Lobby.StartCDP
start java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:MaxPermSize=4000m GameServer.StartGameserver
```

I've heard MaxMetaspaceSize replaced it, so I tried something like this to see if it would work, but the batch program just instantly crashed before it even overflowed:

```
start java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m GameServer.StartGameserver
```

Comment: did you try increasing your meta space.

Comment: 4GB of permgen space? What kind of game are you running?

Comment: Yes, I've tried increasing the meta space too. I don't know if it just works different or what. The game is huge, it's actually a MMORPG that closed several years ago and the source code was released to the public.

Comment: The Perm space has been removed, because of technical drawbacks like not being resizeable. Just remove that option and the Metaspace will be able to grow as long as enough RAM is there. If it fails to grow, because there’s not enough memory, it won’t help to place a limit on it…

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I had to add this to it for it to work:

```
start java Lobby.StartLobby 
start java Lobby.StartCDP
start java -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=4000m -Xmx1g GameServer.StartGameserver
```